# Iterating multi dimensional array with jstl

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, multidimensional-array, jstl

I am trying to iterate through a multidimensional array of string and print its values. But all my loop does is print the first row multiple times.

```
String[][] myArray;
```

**Values in myArray:**

```
Tom     Decker      Male    20
Julie   Hanson      Female  25
Toby    Jackson     Male    30
```

**Loop:**

```
<c:forEach var="rowData" items="${myArray}">
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="cellData" items="${rowData}" >
            <td><c:out value="${cellData}"></c:out></td>                    
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Instead of printing all the data, it prints the first record 3 times like below.

```
Tom     Decker      Male    20
Tom     Decker      Male    20
Tom     Decker      Male    20
```

So it seems that the loops(inner and outer both) are iterating the right number of times. But the outer loop is not pointing to the next record after each iteration.

Comment: I suspect you really have those values which you get as output. Did you confirm it in your Servlet that your array is populated correctly?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed what my array contains in the servlet side.

Comment: Try using the indexed version of the `foreach` tag and access as `${rowData[index]}`.

Comment: In order to exclude JSTL `<c:forEach>` from being the cause, what do you see when you print `${myArray[0][0]}`, `${myArray[1][0]}`, `${myArray[2][0]}`, etc plain vanilla? Do you see "Tom, Julie, Toby" or still "Tom, Tom, Tom"?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an array / List of objects instead of a multidimensional array?  Something like:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String sex; // or enum, whatever
    private int age;

    // public getters/settters go here
}
```

Then your jstl would look more like this:

```
<c:forEach var="rowData" items="${myArray}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${rowData.firstName}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${rowData.lastName}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${rowData.sex}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${rowData.age}"></c:out></td>
    <tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This would give you more flexibility in terms of applying CSS styles to the columns as well if that's what you're into.

Comment: Using objects would have helped but the requirement is to use 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Run nested loop using forach tags and the inner loop, use counter over the loop and render the column with the help of loop index.

Syntax code :

```
<c:forEach var="rowData" items="${myArray}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="cellData" varStatus="loop" items="${rowData}" >
                <td><c:out value="${cellData[loop.index]}"></c:out></td>                    
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```